# Magento 2 : Get product price as per order currency

Tags: magento2, sales-order, multicurrency

I have placed order in euro

& tried to get product price in phtml file of an email template

using below code

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */

```
$_item         = $block->getItem();
$_order        = $_item->getOrder();
$helper        = $this->helper('Vendor\Sales\Helper\Data');
$productObj    = $helper->getProductBySku($_item->getSku());
```

echo `$_order->formatPrice($productObj->getPrice());` // This changes only currency symbol not price exg. ( product price in dollar $11 ) it converts into €11 not €8.

Any thoughts how it can be converted ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in helper

```
public function formatProductPrice($currencyCodeTo, $price)
            {
                $currency = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency();
                return $currency->convert($price, $currencyCodeTo);
            }
```

Call this method & pass required arguments

```
$originalPrice = $helper->formatProductPrice($_order->getOrderCurrencyCode(),$productObj->getPrice('regular_price'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2, there are no 'core' module. You can get this by following way inside view file(.phtml)

$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(50,2),true,false);

If the above does not work you can refer to the solutions here: [How to convert number into currency format in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85100/how-to-convert-number-into-currency-format-in-magento2)